# Dynamic Dependent Select Box using jQuery, Ajax and PHP is not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am new to programming and I am trying different tutorials, guidelines, questions, and answers from StackOverflow and YT videos for 5 days, but I can't make it work so I really need your help because I can't find the problem here.

So far I prefer this tutorial: https://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/ .
I have a form with select options. One selected option (the options coming from my database) influences the following select field (options also coming from my database). I want the options coming from my database so I can change them easily later.

I have a bootstrap CSS template

My **tables**:

**categories**
category_id, category_name, status

**types**
types_id, category_id, types_name, status

**tdetail**
detail_id, types_id, detail_name, status

**Database connection: dbh.php**

```
<?php

// Database configuration 
$serverName = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "name";

// Create database connection 
$conn = mysqli_connect ($serverName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

// Check connection 
if (!$conn){
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

My ajax file **ajaxdata.php**

```
<?php 
// Include the database config file 
include_once 'dbh.php'; 
 
if(!empty($_POST["category_id"])){ 
    // Fetch type data based on the specific category 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM types WHERE category_id = ".$_POST['category_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY types_name ASC"; 
    $result = $conn->query($query); 
     
    // Generate HTML of state options list 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        echo '<option value="">Select the type</option>'; 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['types_id'].'">'.$row['types_name'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">State not available</option>'; 
    } 
}elseif(!empty($_POST["types_id"])){ 
    // Fetch tdetail data based on the specific type 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tdetail WHERE types_id = ".$_POST['types_id']." AND status = 1 ORDER BY detail_name ASC"; 
    $result = $conn->query($query); 
     
    // Generate HTML of tdetail options list 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        echo '<option value="">Select the detail</option>'; 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['detail_id'].'">'.$row['detail_name'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">Detail not available</option>'; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

The **select option in my add-listing.php**:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                            <label class="widget-title">Select the category</label>
                                            <div class="form-group user-chosen-select-container">
                                                <select id="category" name="category" class="user-chosen-select">
                                                    <option value="0">Select the category</option>
                                                    <?php 
                                                    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
                                                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
                                                            echo '<option value="'.$row['category_id'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</option>'; 
                                                        } 
                                                    }else{ 
                                                        echo '<option value="">Category not available</option>'; 
                                                    } 
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>
                                            </div><!-- end form-group -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- end col-lg-12 -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                        <label class="widget-title">Select the type</label>
                                            <div class="form-group user-chosen-select-container">
                                                <select id="cType" name="cType" class="user-chosen-select">
                                                    <option value="">Select the type</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div><!-- end form-group -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- end col-lg-12 -->
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                        <label class="widget-title">Select the detail</label>
                                            <div class="form-group user-chosen-select-container">
                                                <select id="tDetail" name="tDetail" class="user-chosen-select">
                                                    <option value="">Select the detail</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div><!-- end form-group -->
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- end col-lg-12 -->
```

The **script in my add-listing.php**:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#category').on('change', function(){
        var categoryID = $(this).val();
        if(categoryID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'includes/ajaxdata.php',
                data:'category_id='+categoryID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#cType').html(html);
                    $('#tDetail').html('<option value="">Select the type first</option>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#cType').html('<option value="">Select the category first</option>');
            $('#tDetail').html('<option value="">Select the type first</option>'); 
        }
    });
    
    $('#cType').on('change', function(){
        var typeID = $(this).val();
        if(typeID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'includes/ajaxdata.php',
                data:'type_id='+typeID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#tDetail').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#tDetail').html('<option value="">Select type first</option>'); 
        }
    });
});
</script><!-- end script -->
```

This is what I included in my **header of my add-listing.php**:

```
// Include the database config file 
    include_once 'includes/dbh.php';
    
// Fetch all the category data 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY category_name ASC"; 
        $result = $conn->query($query); 
        ?>
```

Instead of

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I loaded it in the footer from my folder

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

So I did everything how described in the tutorial. My site is showing the options in the 1st select field but the following 2 not. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - You need to shorten your question and also include any error messages from Conole or server logs

Comment: Part of the reason for the guideline for asking a question on SO is to make sure you've gone through the debugging process yourself to help narrow the scope of where this might not be working. It's not currently clear where your code isn't working as expected - is the ajax call not working? Is the database query not working? A good starting point would be to determine if the issue with JS or PHP, and then you can narrow your question from there. Check your browser console for any errors and your PHP error log for any errors.